# Select multiple items in ListFragment

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-fragments, android-listfragment

How do you set the ListView in a ListFragment to multiple choice? In a standard activity, I would specify `android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"` in the xml file, and use `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1` as the textViewResourceId while attaching the adapter and all works fine, but in the ListFragment, the items selected are not being highlighted as they should with `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1` and the choice mode is `singleChocie`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How do you set the ListView in a ListFragment to multiple choice?

`getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE)` from Java, or provide your own layout file that uses `android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"` in the `ListView`, in addition to your adapter setup.